# What is the android usb serial port name?

Tags: android, serial-port, pyserial, usb-otg, termux

I wanna connect my wemos(micropython) chip through an android USB port (OTG).

via TERMUX so the USB serial port name is required here,

like 'COM1','COM2' in windows,

Thanx in advance

[Termux using pyserial](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rq5Nt.jpg)

Comment: Take look on `termux-usb`, which is in `termux-api` package. As I understand, USB devices mounted at `/dev/bus/usb/*`. Also suggest to try connect with "Serial USB Terminal" (available in Google Play). Sorry for bad English.

Comment: to access USB serial ports on Android you have to use dedicated libraries like https://github.com/mik3y/usb-serial-for-android and dedicated terminal programs like the already mentioned "Serial USB Terminal"

Answer (score 0):

It is not always the same. I have had the following tty* file names.
$/dev/ttyACM0
$/dev/ttyACM1
$/dev/ttyS0
$/dev/ttyS1

One way to find it is to unplug the USB serial device and do a
$/dev/ls tty*
Then plug it in and repeat the command.

Dont forget to $chmod 777 ttyXXX